How to get original bytes from unicode-string?
I need to get the original byte-sequence from a given unicode-string via Powershell.
I made multiple test, but its not that easy as I thought.
Here a sample that is failing:
$bytes  = [byte[]]@(239,174,61,217,221,117,215,174,248,221,253,56,219,126,53,221,189,122,211,157,26,231,126,57,50,0)
$string = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($bytes)

# here i need a solution to get back $bytes from the unicode-string:
$bytes2  = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($string)

# compare result:
cls
[string]::Join(',', $bytes)
[string]::Join(',', $bytes2)

What is wrong here? I need a solution that gets me the original bytes here.

"bytes" is too generic, it depends on the encoding (and possibly it is the problem, but you forgot to include the results of your test (the output of the last two lines). I would assume you original bytes where UTF-8 encoding, and the results bytes are UTF-16

Encoding.Unicode represents UTF-16, but your bytes are not valid UTF-16, so Unicode.GetString() returns a corrupted string, which is why Unicode.GetBytes() can't recover the bytes. For arbitrary bytes, you can use Encoding.GetEncoding(437) per Is there a code page that matches ASCII and can round trip arbitrary bytes through Unicode?. Always use a proper Encoding that matches the actual byte encoding. But since your bytes don't represent textual data to begin with, you shouldn't be using Encoding at all.


What is wrong here? I need a solution that gets me the original bytes here.

What goes wrong here is that (some of) the original byte pairs don't map to existing unicode characters, and are thus replaced with � - resulting in partial data loss.
If you want byte-string-to-text encoding (eg. for transporting byte streams across text-based protocols like HTTP), base64 is usually the way to go:
# bytes->text
$string = [convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)

# text->bytes
$bytes2 = [convert]::FromBase64String($string)

